# Solutions to a Graeco-Latin grid?

Tags: permutations, latin-square

I have a 4x4 grid of 16 different elements. Each element is composed of two numbers that can be 1-4. **I want to know if I can find a permutation of the grid in which every row and column has 1-4 for each number.** So if this were to be one of the rows:

(1,3), (4, 2), (3, 1), (2, 3)

Then it would have numbers 1-4 for the first number, but only 1, 2, and 3 for the second number. I have a program running on my computer that randomly shuffles the grid and tests it for the condition that I want. **Is it possible to approach the problem logically such that I don't have to sift through 16^16 possible permutations?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem of finding a Graeco-Latin square of order 4. Here is an example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
11&22&33&44\\
34&43&12&21\\
42&31&24&13\\
23&14&41&32\end{bmatrix}$$
If we also require the diagonals to have numbers 1 to 4 for both first and second coordinates, then up to permuting numbers, rotations and reflections, [there are only two solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeco-Latin_square#History).